# Printing (to paper) a grid built with divs - wrong line wrap

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing

I have a dashboard that I have to show on screen and print to paper. It has dates and some colored blocks to form a grid.

On the screen, everything looks right. But when I try to print to paper, rows are broken in the wrong places, even though there's enough space left. I have tried making the grid smaller, but it keeps happening and break lines are introduced wrongly.

I only have this problem in Firefox.  Safari and Chrome are working properly.  I have not tested IE yet.

Here you have some screenshots that show the problem.

This is the way it looks on the screen: 
[image: This is how it looks on the screen]

This is the way it looks when printed (to paper/pdf): 
[image: This is how it looks when I print it]

In this link you can see the html and css that I wrote: [Source code](http://bit.ly/1htFVuC)

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not using a width in pixels for the main container but use the 100%